# Editing toolbar in Xcode 4.6 - unable to add Bar Button Items

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, xcode4.6

I am attempting to add a toolbar as an input accessory, and as such have added it via xcode storyboard editor to the view controller (and not within the view). This was as specified in this tutorial(which seems to be written for an earlier version of xcode): [reference](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/02/27/keyboard-tutorial-part-3-add-a-toolbar-to-the-keyboard/)

My issue: "8.) Now we need to open the toolbar item itself. Double click Toolbar in the document window."

This is no longer valid behavior in Xcode 4.6 it appears, so I ask you: how do I add button items to a toolbar? I would prefer to avoid doing it programmatically (Still reasonably new to xcode development and normally make my GUIs with storyboards) but if I have to, I have to.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue - it was appearing behind the UIView. However you dont ever need to graphically interact witha  toolbar, you can just drag-and-drop controls onto it in the sidebar. If there is a need for more info on this message me or vote up.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing what I think you are doing, adding `UIBarButtonItems` to a `UIToolbar`, then you simply drag a Bar Button Item out to the toolbar.

However, I would assume that what they mean when they say 'double-click' is **not** what people normally think of when they think double click. Try double clicking *slowly* this often does the trick.